# Replicate local database dss

Tags: wso2-esb, esb, wso2-data-services-server

ESB - DSS 4.8.1

We have created two new databases in the Manager Node (cluster) from Carbon console.
We are trying to force traffic for the Worker, but as new databases are Locally registry created in the Manager, it doesn't work.

We have tried to add them to the Worker's `master-datasources.xml`, to a new `custom-datasources.xml`, and modifying `datasources.properties` with no success.
What are we doing wrong? has sense the test we are trying to run?

Thanks in advance